# Filtering a GROUP BY view like HAVING

Tags: sql

I've a table Sales like this:

```
CLIENT, PRODUCT, SALEDATE
Peter, Phone, 2013/02/01
Peter, Phone, 2012/11/15
Peter, Phone, 2010/01/01
```

I've this view named LastSale:

```
SELECT Client, Product, MAX(SaleDate)
FROM Sales
GROUP BY Client, Product
```

If we execute this view, the result must be

```
Peter, Phone, 2013/02/01
```

Now my problem is that I'm using this view in a program filtering by SaleDate, for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM LastSale
WHERE SaleDate < '2013/01/01'
```

And this SQL gives me no result because MAX(SaleDate) is not < '2013/01/01', but there are a date that fit the request (2012/11/15).

I know this can be done with a HAVING clause in the view, but in my program I'm accessing the view, so I can't change it. there are any way to get the result I want?

Thanks in advance, and excuse my poor English.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use MAX(salesdate) it will automatically give you just the max (1 row)

try this

```
    SELECT Client, Product,SaleDate
    FROM Sales
    WHERE SaleDate < '2013-01-01'
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52cc8f/2)

if you want group by `Client` then try this to give distinct client

```
 SELECT Client, Product,SaleDate
 FROM Sales
 WHERE SaleDate < '2013-01-01'
 group by Client
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52cc8f/3)

Answer (score 0):

If I've got it right you should select from your original table not from the View:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales
WHERE SaleDate < '2013/01/01'
```

Answer (score 0):

The new request against original table is necessary to you because view doesn't correspond to a condition. At first WHERE clause and then GROUP BY

```
SELECT Client, Product, MAX(SaleDate)
FROM LastSale
WHERE SaleDate < '2013/01/01'
GROUP BY Client, Product
```